# BeautifulSoup scraping additional data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python and BeautifulSoup to scrape some data from [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/) site.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

eclipse_time_date = requests.get("https://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(eclipse_time_date.text, 'html.parser')

eclipse_info = soup.find_all("div", class_= "six columns art__eclipse-txt")

for info in eclipse_info:
    print("Eclipse Date: {0}".format(info.find('a').text))
    print("Location: {0}".format(info.find('p').text))
```

**Output:**

```
Eclipse Date: July 13, 2018 — Partial Solar Eclipse
Location: South in Australia, Pacific, Indian Ocean New Features: Path Map | 3D Path Globe | Eclipse Information

Eclipse Date: July 27, 2018 — Total Lunar Eclipse
Location: Much of Europe, Much of Asia, Australia, Africa, South in North America, South America, Pacific, Atlantic, Indian Ocean, Antarctica New Features: Path Map | 3D Path Globe | Eclipse Information
```

My problem is, the part after the locations, ` New Features:` etc, also has a `p` tag. How do I ignore that part so my output is:

```
Eclipse Date: July 13, 2018 — Partial Solar Eclipse
Location: South in Australia, Pacific, Indian Ocean

Eclipse Date: July 27, 2018 — Total Lunar Eclipse
Location: Much of Europe, Much of Asia, Australia, Africa, South in North America, South America, Pacific, Atlantic, Indian Ocean, Antarctica
```

I could use `split()`, and find the index of New, however, some places have the word New in the location, for example, "New York" or "New Orleans".

I would like to know if there is a method to extract the data using BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the HTML data by using the `article` tag, and then creating more advanced groupings:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = soup(requests.get('https://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/').text, 'html.parser')  
groups = [i for i in s.find_all('article', {'class':'art__eclipse-nxt pdflexi'})]
new_groups = [[getattr(i, c) for c in ['figcaption', 'h3', 'p']] for i in groups]
for date, title, description in new_groups:
  print('Title: {}'.format(title.text))
  print('Date: {}'.format(date.text))
  print('Description: {}'.format(soup(re.sub('\<i class\="i-font"\>\</i\>', '', str(description)), 'html.parser').find('p').text))
  print('-'*20)
```

Output:

```
Title: July 13, 2018 — Partial Solar Eclipse
Date: Jul 13, 2018
Description: South in Australia, Pacific, Indian Ocean New Features: 
Path Map | 3D Path Globe | Eclipse Information
--------------------
Title: July 27, 2018 — Total Lunar Eclipse
Date: Jul 27, 2018
Description: Much of Europe, Much of Asia, Australia, Africa, South in 
North America, South America, Pacific, Atlantic, Indian Ocean, 
Antarctica New Features: Path Map | 3D Path Globe | Eclipse Information
--------------------
```

Comment: You see the part with the icon followed by `New Features`? I want that part gone from the text. So it's just `Title` `Description`